tsup --watch Rebuilding/Restarting When server.listen is Used in Fastify App on macOS 15.0.1
I'm developing a Fastify application on macOS 15.0.1, and I'm having issues with rebuilding and restarting the app whenever I include server.listen. I’ve tried tsup for watching and rebuilding, but as soon as I add server.listen, the watch mode stops detecting file changes.
Here’s a breakdown of my setup:
import buildServer from './server';

async function main(): Promise<void> {
  const server = await buildServer();

  server.listen({ port: 4000, host: '0.0.0.0' });
}

void main();

server.ts
import type { FastifyInstance } from 'fastify';
import fastifyHelmet from '@fastify/helmet';
import Fastify from 'fastify';
import { serverOptions } from './configs';

const server = Fastify(serverOptions);

async function buildServer(): Promise<FastifyInstance> {
  server.register(fastifyHelmet);
  return server;
}

export default buildServer;

tsup
import { defineConfig } from 'tsup';

export default defineConfig(options => ({
  entry: ['src/**/*.ts'],
  clean: true,
  format: ['cjs'],
  ...options,
}));

Command for tsup:
tsup --watch --onSuccess 'node dist/index.js'


This requires to check how it works as it doesn't document this well. I'd expect it to work this way. Probably needs a correct cleanup in onSuccess instead of expecting that it will kill a process. I'd suggest to the issues or discussions because the tool is niche

I've encountered the same issue, and downgrading to tsup v8.3.0 resolves it for now.
